# Why the date functions give an error on Excel

Tags: excel

I want to convert 04.01.2022 to 2022-01-04 format and wrote
YEAR($A$5)&"-"&TEXT(MONTH($A$5),"00")&"-"&TEXT(DAY($A$5),"00")
this function in Excel and it gave me #VALUE! error. How can I solve it?

Comment: Is the value in `A5` text looking like a date or an actual number looking like a date through formatting? With the latter, you could easily just change the number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell is formatted and recognised as a true date, which I suspect it's not, then you can use the `TEXT` function to format the date as you need be ...

```
=TEXT(A5,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

... if it's not formatted as a date then you need to do that ...

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A5,".","/")),"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I changed the date format of PC to Russian and the function worked.